# Sort rows taking too long

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm new to Pentaho.

The following transformation seems to be correct.

However, it is taking eternities to sort the rows:

[image]

This is the step:

[image]

Why is this taking so long and how can I improve this?

This is Merge join 2:
[image: e]

Comment: Apparently you can increase the memory that the step uses from the JVM, that's the 'Free memory threshold (in %)' parameter you can set in the step. Since we are talking VM, we can't know 100% how much free memory is available, so try to increase it a little bit and see if it runs faster.

Comment: Thanks, I've set the memory to 90% but it doesn't run!

Comment: It looks like the output buffer of the sort step is full somehow. Is the merge 2 step using the keys in the same order you sort them in? It looks very strange when the sort step is still running but the Merge 2 already finished.

Comment: @Cyrus, thanks for helping, pls see my edited question above.

Comment: Ah, that explains a lot. Merge 2 list the Time step for both inputs. That means it doesn't use the input rows from the Sort step at all and the stream stalls when the buffer reaches 10k rows. Change the first step to Sort rows. Also, if you want to merge by time_key only, you should sort on that.

Comment: @Cyrus do you mean, should I add a step with "sort rows" before the 1st Merge join? Whyd don't you post an answer (i'll accept it if it works)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this in the transformation properties ( ctrl + T or View -> Settings ):

- Set a bigger nr of rows in rowset
- Set a bigger Feedback size
- Uncheck "Manage Thread priorities?"

Example:
[Transformation properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYaHv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Step 'Merge join2' has Time-step as input twice. Because 'Sort rows' is not defined as input-step in 'Merge join2' the records from 'Sort rows' are not processed. If de buffer is on 10000 'Sort rows' stops writing to 'Merge join2'. Step 'Sort rows' will therefore never finish.

Answer (score 0):

few ways I tried to work with sort.. hope this helps

1. Use the Sort size (rows in memory) setting on the Sort rows step to control this. The Free memory threshold (in %) helps avoid filling up available memory. Be sure to allocate enough RAM to PDI.
2. Leverage database push the data to staging and sort and populate the target table works quick in term of batch processing.